# UIButton leads to UITextField word deletion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have question on word deleting using a UIButton

E.g. there are 10 letters in the UITextField. I coded by pressing the UIButton so i can have a backspace or delete function to delete letters one by one. However, i only want the user able to delete the last 5 letters among the 10 letters. How can i restrict that?

Here is my code,

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
    if ([display.text length] != 0) {
        display.text = [display.text substringToIndex:[display.text length]-1];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([display.text length] > 5) {
    display.text = [display.text substringToIndex:[display.text length]-1];
}
```